# How to make keyboard shortcuts for Beamer that cycle through frames

Tags: beamer, viewers, keyboard

I'm making a presentation in Beamer, and I'm using the `\uncover` command to reveal certain parts of my frames in a certain order. I plan to show the resulting `PDF` with Adobe Acrobat during my presentation.

**My problem:** I cannot figure out a way how to cycle through just the frames. That is, I would like there to be two buttons (or two combinations of buttons) on my keyboard, which, when pressed, either go to the next frame with all `\uncover`s activated, or to the previous frame, also with all `\uncover`s activated. Since my presentation has a lot of steps in each frame, I would like to skip over them if I need to refer back to them later in the presentation.

The right arrow/down arrow/page down buttons all do the same thing (just go to the next page in the document, which is not necessarily the next frame), and I've tried different combinations, with Shift, Alt, Ctrl, Cmd, but nothing works in the way I would like it to. I do get some weird behavior with Tab, which skips to the beginning and then to the same (seemingly) random frame (I haven't been able to deduce what exactly Tab does).

Comment: With Adobe Reader, `Tab` allows to browse all the links (and other active regions) of the current page in their order of appearance (reverse order with `Shift`) then press `Space` to activate this link. If the two last links of each frame are "next frame" and "prev frame", you may use `Shift+Tab,Space` to go to the next frame and `Shift+Tab,Shift+Tab,Space` to go to the previous frame...

Comment: @PaulGaborit This doesn't seem to work for me. Just pressing `Shift` does nothing, and `Shift+Tab` seems to do the same thing as just `Tab`. `Space` has the some result as `Down arrow` or `Right arrow` or `Left click` (in full-screen mode), and the combinations you give also don't seem to do anything different. Maybe I should mention that I'm using Adobe Acrobat X Pro on Mac OS 10.9. I tried using bookmarks, but I don't know how to cycle through them. Also "Previous view" and "Next view" would work if they were not temporary and constantly updating.

Comment: `Tab` and `Shift+Tab` allows to browse all the links (look at a gray dashed rectangle). Then `Space` (on Linux), `Shift+Enter` (on Windows) or `???` (on Mac OS X) activates the selected link... See more [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/keyboard-shortcuts.html).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not about latex but a feature of the pdf viewer